# Problem implementing event to command behaviour on Google map Pins

Tags: google-maps, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior) article to create a event to command behaviour on Google maps. Here is my xaml

```
 <maps:Map x:Name="map" HeightRequest="200"
              ItemsSource="{Binding FutsalPins}"  >

     <maps:Map.Behaviors>
         <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="MapClicked" Command="{Binding MapClickedCommand}" />
     </maps:Map.Behaviors>

     <maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <maps:Pin Position="{Binding Position}" 
                       Address="{Binding Address}"
                       Label="{Binding Description}" >

                 <maps:Pin.Behaviors>
                     <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Clicked" Command="{Binding PinClickedCommand}" />
                 </maps:Pin.Behaviors>
             </maps:Pin>
         </DataTemplate>
     </maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
 </maps:Map>
```

the maps:Map.Behaviours is working as expected. However for

```
maps:Pin.Behaviors
```

I get an an error saying

> Error     Position 31:34. No property, bindable property, or event found
>   for 'Behaviors', or mismatching type between value and property.
>
> Error XLS0415 The attachable property 'Behaviors' was not found in
>   type 'Pin'.

Comment: Doesn't seem that `Pin` inherits `Behavior`.. Perhaps your best bet is attach the behavior by [hand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/attached)

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error Position 31:34. No property, bindable property, or event found
>   for 'Behaviors', or mismatching type between value and property.
>
> Error XLS0415 The attachable property 'Behaviors' was not found in
>   type 'Pin'.

As the [Pin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.maps.pin?view=xamarin-forms#properties) class doesn't have the `Behaviors` property.

The Pin class defines a `MarkerClicked` event, which is fired when a Pin is tapped and it also defines a `InfoWindowClicked` event that's fired when an information window is tapped.You could see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/pins#interact-with-a-pin).

And you also could try `Clicked` event directly.

```
<maps:Pin Position="{Binding Position}" Clicked="Pin_Clicked
                      Address="{Binding Address}"
                      Label="{Binding Description}" >                     
</maps:Pin>
```

Comment: @Rabin if you want use command ,you could first handle your clicke event,then in the `Pin_Clicked` method which in the behind code call your command.(as a workaround)

Comment: Ya I might have to do that. Thanks for ur response

Comment: @Rabin if it is helpful，could you mark it，thank you！